# How can I pre-filter or limit report data to just include the latest report date set?

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I've got data in a Google Sheet. There are X # of rows for specific report dates. As more data is dumped into the sheet, X # of rows are added and tagged with that report date.

## This is a sample of the source data in a Google Sheet:

| Report Date | ID | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | ... |
| 2022-01-01 | 2 | ... |
| 2022-01-01 | 3 | ... |
| 2022-02-01 | 1 | ... |
| 2022-02-01 | 2 | ... |
| 2022-02-01 | 3 | ... |
| 2022-01-15 | 1 | ... |
| 2022-01-15 | 2 | ... |
| 2022-01-15 | 3 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 | ... |
| 2021-01-01 | 2 | ... |
| 2021-01-01 | 3 | ... |

I have this added as a data source to Data Studio and created a table with the data like so:

[image]

I want to have the report automatically shows only the data for the last/latest report date set. So in the above example it would be `2022-02-01`:

| Report Date | ID | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 | 1 | ... |
| 2022-02-01 | 2 | ... |
| 2022-02-01 | 3 | ... |

More data would be added to the sheet, so the logic in Data Studio has to be dynamic.

**Sample data**:

- Data set ([Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TzUljd2l28xDO7Uz-qILCIQdaHO0NyWrljno-XcLnQQ/edit?usp=sharing))
- [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/7c315baf-e29c-43cb-8f28-61abd9a497b5) report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved with a [blend](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061420) and creating a `MAX(Date)` field (a date field aggregated by [`MAX`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583208)) and using it as a metric and join condition so that only the latest date and respective data are displayed:

### 1) Blend Fields

| Table 1 | Table 2 |
| --- | --- |
|  | ***Dimension 1***: `Report Date` |
|  | ***Dimension 2***: `ID` |
| ***Metric 1*** ***Name***: `Report Date` ***Formula***: `MAX(Report Date)` |  |
| ***Date Range***: `Report Date` (Auto) |  |
| [image: blend_table_!] | [image: blend_image_2] |

### 2) Join Configuration

| Join Description | Table 1 Table 2 |
| --- | --- |
| **Join Operator** | Left Outer |
| **Join Condition** | `Report Date (Table 1)` `Report Date (Table 2)` |
| **Image** | [image: join_config] |

In summary the blend will look like:

[image: blend_summary]

Publicly editable [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/d0401dd9-df73-4b4d-802f-b854249de68e) report (embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p3An2Ma4ccuct91iZXn1mwOubjn7cwel-kcfOewxF1w/edit?usp=sharing) data source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: gif]