# How to filter by last max value/date on DataStudio?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have a BigQuery dataset updating on irregular times (can be once, twice a week, or less). Data is structured as following.

| id | Column1 | Column2 | data_date(timestamp) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Datapoint0 | Datapoint00 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | Datapoint1 | Datapoint01 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | Datapoint2 | Datapoint02 | 2022-01-03 |
| 3 | Datapoint3 | Datapoint03 | 2022-01-03 |
| 4 | Datapoint4 | Datapoint04 | 2022-02-01 |
| 5 | Datapoint5 | Datapoint05 | 2022-02-01 |
| 6 | Datapoint6 | Datapoint06 | 2022-02-15 |
| 7 | Datapoint7 | Datapoint07 | 2022-02-15 |

Timestamp is a string in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.
I want to make a chart and a pivot table in Google DataStudio that automatically filters by the latest datapoints ('2022-02-15' in the example). All the solutions I tried are either sub-optimal or just don't work:

- Creating a support column doesn't work because I need to mix aggregated and non-aggregated fields (data_date and the latest data_date)
  [image: Error message: Invalid formula - Invalid input expression. - Aggregated and non-aggregated fields cannot be mixed in a Boolean Expression]
- Adding a filter to the charts allows me to specify only a specific day - I would need to edit the chart regularly every time the underlyind data is updated[image: static_filter]
- Using a dropdown filter allows me to dynamically filter whatever date I need. However I consider it suboptimal because I can't have it automatically select the latest date. Having a date filter  can make it dynamic, but since the update time is not regular it may select a date range with multiple timestamps/or none at all, so it's also a sub-optimal solution[image: Date filter 1] [image: Date filter 2]

Honestly I'm out of ideas. I stupidly thought it was possible to add a column saying `data_date = (select max(data_date) from dataset`, but it seems not possible since max needs to work on aggregated data.

Comment: ABO, [edit] the question with a publicly editable Google Data Studio that includes the necessary information along with a recreation of the details provided in the question (data set, attempt at solving, chart configuration, controls, filter(s), calculated field(s) etc). Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test a suggestion as the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73053945/how-can-i-pre-filter-or-limit-report-data-to-just-include-the-latest-report-date This post provides a solution

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution could be creating a `view` that can have the latest data point, and referencing the view from the `data studio`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `project_id.dataset_id.table_name` AS
SELECT *
FROM `bigquery-public-data.covid19_ecdc_eu.covid_19_geographic_distribution_worldwide`
ORDER BY date DESC  # or timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```